# Yii Framework - composite route of request

Tags: yii, routes

May I make a route of request not two-composite (*controler/action*), but consisting of **bigger number of parts** in *YII*?

Comment: Question is vague. What are you trying to do exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set route parameters like this:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
    'urlFormat'=>'path',
    'showScriptName'=>false,
    'rules'=>array(
        array('<controller>/<action>', 'pattern'=>'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<relation:\w+>/<relationId:\d+>'),
    ),
),
```

Variables `relation` and `relationId` will be available in action method like `GET` parameters.
e.g. url `user/update/car/12` will call `user` controller and `update` action, and in `GET` array will be available variables `relation='car'` and `relationId=12`